# Rotate Secrets using Azure Key VAult

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault

I have a number of cosmos db deployed and would like to automatically manage the secrets and keys for the same. I am looking at KeyVault integration documents and found these :

Manage storage account using AKV:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview-storage-keys-powershell#manage-storage-account-keys

Use Azure Automation for Key rotation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-key-rotation-log-monitoring#key-rotation-using-azure-automation

I would like to know if there is inbuilt support from Cosmos team for AKV integration to maintain secrets/keys ?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support to directly rotate keys in Cosmos DB and update AKV. You will need to write and run a PowerShell or az cli script to do this.

Here are samples for regenerating keys for Cosmos.
PS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-powershell#regenerate-keys

cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-cli#regenerate-account-key

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: is it still the case that we can't directly rotate keys of Cosmos DB and update AKV?

Comment: You can use azure function to automate process (which use PSH to regenerate and update secret with new key):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation-dual?tabs=azure-cli#key-vault-rotation-functions-for-two-sets-of-credentials